# MongoDB aggregation does not work (or is very slow) with PHP and works perfectly in shell?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregate method on my collection (containing more than 20M documents).

I first tried it in the Windows shell :

```
db.data.aggregate([
{$match: {firstname: "Roger"}},
{$group:{"_id":"$id_car",count:{$sum: 1}}},
{$sort: {count: -1}},
{$limit: 50}])
```

And it works perfectly, returning the results after a few seconds.

When I "translate" it in PHP :

```
$data = $db->data;
$ops = array(
    array(
         '$match' => array(
             'firstname' => 'Roger'
         )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$id_car',
            'count' => array(
                '$sum' => 1     
            )       
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'count' => -1
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$limit' => 4       
    )
);
$res = $data->aggregate($ops);
```

I get a timeout PHP Fatal error :

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'localhost:27017: cursor timed out (timeout: 30000, time left: 30:0, status: 0)'
```

I don't know if I've made a mistake in my PHP code, or if aggregate is supposed to be much slower in PHP than in shell ?

Also, I have added an index on "firstname" field to make the query go faster.

By the way, is there any way to set the timeout to infinity for this kind of call ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Joe

Comment: one thing you can do do debug further (and post here) - see what that query you are running looks like in the `mongod` logs.  If it is really timing out then it will show up in there eventually once it completes and you can get an idea of what PHP is actually sending.

Comment: hi Adam, thanks a lot for your help. Could you please tell me how to use debug with mongo and where I can find this log ? i'm really new to this technology ...

Comment: where the log lives will depend on how you have `mongod` configured - the `--logpath` option (or equivalent setting in the config file) will control where the log lives.  The default in Ubuntu for example is `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`. Any query taking over 100ms to complete will be logged by default, so no need for any special mode, just have a look for a slow query around the time you perform a test and you should find what you need.

Comment: According to the comment at end of this link: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursortimeoutexception.php MongoCursor::$timeout = -1; turns off timeouts.

Comment: Can't see any point why this should be slower in PHP than in shell. Nearly all the work is done on server side. Only difference I can see is that you're using in PHP a limit of 4 rather than 50. But that should only speed things up...What does your memory consumption say? try mongostat once for shell and for PHP and see if you can see  any difference.

Comment: Is the shell and the php script running on the same server?
The onlything I can think of would be network issue?
The PHP driver really doesn't do anything for commands, just passes them almost directly through

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know about your issue (PHP being slower than the MongoShell), but something I've done that allowed me to run an aggregation in PHP (due to the timeout problems) is changing the way I invoked the aggregation.

Hope this helps someone that reaches this page because of the timeout problems, like I did!

Instead of `$data->aggregate($ops)` I ran the following equivalent to your case:

```
$db->command(
    array('aggregate' => 'data', 'pipeline' => $ops),
    array('timeout' => 100000000)
)
```

Notice that you must run the command over the `$db` and not your collection.